# Getting a spurious fibre trace with zip and for comprehension

Tags: scala, zio

I have just started to look at ZIO to try to improve my Scala. I have started by trying to update some of my old code. I have wrapped some legacy code which returns a configuration wrapped in an option and I'm converting that to a ZIO which I'm then using in for comprehension.

The code works as expected but if I return `None` I get:

```
Fiber failed.
A checked error was not handled.
None

Fiber:Id(1612612180323,1) was supposed to continue to:
  a future continuation at tryzio.MyApp$.run(MyApp.scala:94)
  a future continuation at zio.ZIO.exitCode(ZIO.scala:543)

Fiber:Id(1612612180323,1) execution trace:
  at zio.ZIO$.fromOption(ZIO.scala:3246)
  at tryzio.MyApp$.run(MyApp.scala:93)
```

The code works as expected for both a `Some` and a `None`, but I get the spurious Fibre messages for a `None`.

The code that generates this is really very simple:

```
def run(args: List[String]) = ({

for {
  cmdln <- ZIO.fromOption(getConfig(args.toArray))
  _ <- putStrLn("Model Data Builder")
  _ <- putStrLn(s"\nVerbose: ${cmdln.verbose}")
  } yield()


}).exitCode
```

But I have clearly missed something obvious! I'm new to ZIO so please use small words when explains my lack of understanding. Do I need to join all Fibres? I have tried to catch the `None` and then exit but actually my code never strops running if I do that - Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.exitCode` caught an error (empty configuration) which hasn't been handled in the code, printed debug information in `stdErr` and exited the program with status `1`. So it works as expected.

I agree that the error message is a bit misleading and should start with something something business-related rather than `fiber failed`.
You might fire a ticket on github.

Comment: It all made sense to me once I added a .orElse(ZIO.none) to the for comprehension and my error went away! Thanks @simpadjo for making me think more about what I was doing!